# Saving Nested Case Class With Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to work out how to save nested case classes with Spark Cassandra Connector.  As a simple example:

Case classes:

```
case class Foo(id: String, bar: Bar)
case class Bar(field1: String)
```

Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id text, field1 text, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Spark code:

```
val foo = Foo("a", Bar("b"))
val fooRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(foo))
fooRdd.saveToCassandra(cassandraKeyspace, "foo")
```

Results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Columns not found in Foo: [field1]
```

I realise I could make a new case class that flattens out Foo, but I'd rather not do this if possible.  Ive played around with Column Mappers but to no avail.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? `fooRdd2.saveToCassandra(cassandraKeyspace, "foo", SomeColumns("id", "field1" as "bar.field1"))` doesn't work either

Comment: not a nice one- I ended up making a custom RowWriter as described at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md.